# MIPS language to avoid pipeline stalls

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Regarding the MIPS assembly language which is thought in the pattersson's book, I have a question with inserting NOP between instructions to avoid pipeline stalls.

Consider the following code

```
lw   $s5, -16($s5)
sw   $s5, -16($s5)
add  $s5, $s5, $s5
```

We see there is a RAW hazard for $s5 between `lw` and `sw`. There is also a WAW hazard for $s5 betwween `sw` and `add`. So we have to insert two NOPs to avoid stalls. In other words, the pipeline diagram is

```
lw      IF     ID     EX     MEM     WB
sw             IF     ID     ---     EX     MEM     WB
add                   IF     ID      EX     MEM     --     WB
```

When `sw` is going to be executed, it has be wait for `lw` to put the data in a register. Therefore, there is one bubble. Also, when `add` wants to write the final result, it has to wait for the completion of the previous instruction (`sw`). That is another bubble.

So the modified code is

```
lw
NOP
sw
NOP
add
```

But the solution propose the following code

```
lw
NOP
NOP
sw
add
```

Which one is correct? I think mine!

Comment: Kind of poor style to completely replace a question like that.. now my answer seems completely random/unrelated

Comment: @harold : I'm tempted to rollback the last change for that reason. Temptation too strong, I've reverted back to the previous version. If mahmood wants an answer to his newer question he can simply ask a new question on SO.

Comment: I first asked part of the exercise and got an answer which was reasnable but mine was different. Later I saw that the answer is not applicable to the second part of the exercise. So, I replaced that... If I did wrong, I have to say sorry...

Comment: @mahmood : no problem. In cases like that you should leave the question as is, and if you have a more specific question(or a different one) it is best to ask a new question. That allows the questions/answers/comments to match so they make sense to a person who stumbles on this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a fairly standard pipeline, that WAW hazard doesn't exist, it might look sort of hazardy in the program code (in the sense that there are multiple writes to the same register), but there is no mechanism by which the ADD can complete before (or during) the LW (that would mean it calculated the result before the input was available). The SW doesn't write to a register so it doesn't matter, but the ADD can't complete before it either. Actually WAW hazards don't exist at all in the standard pipeline because instructions simply write back in order.

Your solution for the RAW hazard assumes there is WB->EX forwarding, which judging by their solution, there isn't. Without forwarders, the soonest you can use a result is when the ID of reading instruction lines up with the WB of the writing instruction.

---

> Why (WB) and (EX) are not executed in one cycle?

Because it doesn't work. It doesn't work in question `a` either so I'm not sure what happened there. The premise of the question is that there is no forwarding to EX, so same as before, the soonest you can use a value after it is produced is when you line the ID of the reading instruction up with the WB of the writing instruction. EX just reads its inputs from the ID/EX pipeline register.

> Also, for (a), I don't see any WAR on $6 from I1 to I3. Do you??

No, since neither I1 nor I3 modify $6, it's impossible to have any hazard. RAR is not a hazard.

Comment: Regarding your phrase `The SW doesn't write to a register so it doesn't matter, but the ADD can't complete before it either`, but we can do that in the standard5-stage pipeline for two independent instructions. Right? Here, both instructions operate on the same register, but in general with the 5-stage pipeline, I can write a fourth instruction which operate on other registers and we see that it will be finished even before the add. Do you agree with that?

Comment: I mean a diagram like this
`IF   ID   --    --  EX   MEM   WB`
and `IF   ID   EX   MEM   WD` for an independent instruction. As you can see, the second instruction is finished before the first one. Did we break the rule of ordering?

Comment: @mahmood but you can't cause that situation. Any time you insert a bubble, you hold up the next instruction(s) as well. That second instruction can't "go first", the hardware that could make that happen just isn't in the standard pipeline

Comment: What about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941907/understanding-mips-assembly-with-pipelining

Comment: Excuse me.... I updated the post to include the solution proposed by Pattersson... The question is now clear... your answer is also against that.

Comment: Thanks for that.... Unfortunately, the solution manual is not as reliable as the textbook and in some case is in the opposite direction.... A similar problem (an exercise) as been discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640492/convert-c-to-mips-nested-arrays