# understanding MIPS assembly with pipelining

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

With the standard 5-stage pipeline for the MIPS architecture and assuming some instructions depend on each other, how the pipeline bubbles are inserted to the following assembly code?

```
I1: lw   $1, 0($0)
I2: lw   $2, 4($0)
I3: add  $3, $1, $2      ; I1 & I2 -> I3
I4: sw   $3, 12($0)      ; I3 -> I4
I5: lw   $4, 8($0)
I6: add  $5, $1, $4      ; I1 & I5 -> I6
I7: sw   $5, 16($0)      ; I6 -> I7
```

In the first place that we insert a bubble, we

```
I1:  IF   ID   EX   MEM   WB 
I2:       IF   ID   EX    MEM
I3:            IF   ID    --
I4:                 IF    ID
```

As you can see, while I3 is stalled, I4 can proceed for decoding. Isn't that right? Next,

```
I1:  IF   ID   EX   MEM   WB 
I2:       IF   ID   EX    MEM   WB
I3:            IF   ID    --    EX   MEM  WB
I4:                 IF    ID    --   --   EX   MEM   WB
I5:                       IF    ID   EX   MEM  WB 
I6:                             IF   ID   --   EX    MEM   WB
I7:                                  IF   ID   --    --    EX   MEM   WB
```

I think that is possible with the standard pipeline of MIPS, but some say that whenever a bubble is inserted the whole pipeline is stalled. How that can be figured out?

Comment: In the general case, if you just bubble the current instruction you will overlap the stages with the subsequent instruction so you need to bubble all the rest too. If for some reason the subsequent ones also need a bubble then it could work, but then they would wait anyway.

Comment: How do you represent that? Do you mean that the 5th column is all `--`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous question you were using Patterson's book, so let me borrow one of its diagrams:

[image: hazard detection unit]

The important bit here is the hazard detection unit, which is causing the bubbles. If you've read the accompanying text, you know that the method by which it does that is

- NOP out the control signals,
- *pause IF* (keep the IF/ID buffer fixed and don't advance PC)

Which means that your pipeline diagram cannot happen like that. There will not be a new instruction entering every cycle. Also consider that if you had different code, you could have arranged for hardware hazards to happen, as Jester described. So that's obviously bad, and the solution is stalling IF.

This is what would happen:

```
I1:  IF   ID   EX   MEM   WB 
I2:       IF   ID   EX    MEM   WB
I3:            IF   ID    --    --    --
I3:                 IF    ID    --    --    --
I3:                       IF    ID    EX    MEM   WB
I4:                             IF    ID    --    --    --
```

etc.

Comment: But there is a minor problem with the diagram. In the 4th column, when I3 is in the ID stage, I4 is in the IF stage. You ignored that.... If you continue to draw, you will see it is a bizarre! My problem is, when pipeline stalls, what happens to the other next instruction which are fetched and decoded. Do they proceed?

Comment: @mahmood no the point is the next instruction is not fetched and decoded. The same instruction is again decoded, until it no longer has to stall.

Comment: Well in the 4th column, I1(MEM), I2(EX), I3(ID), there is no stall yet. Right? So the next instruction, I4, is feed to the IF stage. Why no fetch? In the 4th column there is no sign of stall

Comment: @mahmood well you could look at it like that, but it will lock the IF/ID pipeline register and so I3 will again appear. I can't indicate I4 being "uselessly fetched" (fetched and then discarded) in this type of diagram though.

Comment: I agree with you because we are humans so we can think. But CPU sees no stall, so it fetches another instruction, I4. Then we have to develop a mechanism to squash or halt the execution.